# ASP.Net mvc 3 LINQ to SQL InsertOnSubmit, primary key duplication

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-3, primary-key

I'm trying to learn a bit of ASP.net MVC 3 and I'm facing a very weired issue.

I have this very simple code controller for a creation of a message.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Message message)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = new BooksDB();
            db.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(message);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(message);
        }
    }
    return View(message);
}
```

The creation is ok for the first register but the primary key is 0 !?!

When i try to add another message, i have an exception :

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Messages'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Messages'. The statement has been terminated.`

I do not understand why the primary key is forced to 0 into a `InsertOnSubmit()`. It should be automatically incremented.

The view is generated using scaffolding and doesn't submit anything for the Id field.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not appear to have `Identity` autogenerated values on in the database for the `id` field in question. You not only must specify the field as the primary key, but if you want the values autogenerated, you have to specify that, as well:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeField] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OtherField] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [id] ASC
    )
)
```

You can set the field to an identity value in SSMS, too

Comment: You were right, my primary key wasn't a Identity column! Thanks :)

Comment: I know because it's a frequent thing I forget to do! :p

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons might be:

- your primary key is coming from client-side and it is being bind by model binder (try looking at your request with Fiddler or FireBug)
- your primary key is not an identity column in database (it doesn't auto increment)
- there is a problem with your Linq to Sql generated classes (a column which is auto incremented should have ColumnAttribute with AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert and IsDbGenerated=true)